# Confusion about ADR in ARM (assembly code)

Tags: arm, assembly, register, c++

I'm confused on what's happening with `ADR R14,cnt1`. Is `cnt1` signifying the end of the program? And if so how will `B sumi` get called? In the ARM manual, it said that `ADR` takes in `PC` but I don't see that here.

c++:

```
s = 0;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   s += i;
```

assembly:

```
sumi: 
MOV R0,#0 
MOV R1,#1

next:
CMP R1,R2 
BGT end
ADD R0,R0,R1 
ADD R1,R1,#1 
B next

end: MOV PC,R14
```

---

```
ADR R14,cnt1
B sumi 
cnt1: ; ...
```

Comment: Here is a minimal ADR example with an assertion: https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/44612c012d2dd8cd188d0d8f96b96711cf4bbd87/v7/adr.S and here is some further explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906688/what-are-the-semantics-of-adrp-and-adrl-instructions-in-arm-assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of the program, the ARM pseudo-instruction `ADR R14, cnt1` loads an address (`cnt1` - end of this part of the program) into a register (`R14`). In practice, `ADR` is replaced by an `ADD` or `SUB` instruction involving the contents of the PC (`R15`). The calculation is based on the offset between the PC and the address in question - taking into account that the PC displacement due to the operation of ARM pipeline. It's easier let the assembler calculate the addresses for you. If the code is changed, the addresses as well, but `ADR` will take care of this when reassembled.

The instruction `B sumi` is just an unconditional jump to the address given by `sumi` (start of the subroutine).

At the end of the loop, the `MOV PC,R14` instruction is executed, causing the PC to be loaded with the content (an address) of `R14` register - remember that the latter was previously modified by the `ADR` instruction. So the program continues jumping to the address given by the label `cnt1`.

When programming subroutines in Assembly,  usually a combination of the `B` and `BL` jump instructions is employed - the latter (branch and link) already stores the return address into `R14` (LR - link register).